# mongodb issue with db connection

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to alter data from a docker container running MongoDB.

I am able to connect using this connection string (don't worry about the user and pass its all local testing).

```
mongo mongodb://root:example@172.19.0.7:27017/opal_data?authSource=admin
```

However, when I try to use mongoimport or mongoexport things do not work.

```
mongoexport --collection=652923b6ba96b245eae830e1_variable --uri=mongodb://root:example@172.19.0.7:27017/opal_data?authSource=admin --out=json-ex.json
```

Will get stuck waiting infinitely.

```
mongoimport --collection 65290895ba96b245eae82fb4_variable --file ~/Documents/OPAL_SCRIPTS/test2.json --uri mongodb://root:example@172.19.0.7:27017/opal_data?authSource=admin --jsonArray
```

Will get stuck uploading 0B like this:

```
2023-10-13T11:56:29.258+0200    [........................] opal_data.65290895ba96b245eae82fb4_variable  0B/287B (0.0%)
2023-10-13T11:56:32.257+0200    [........................] opal_data.65290895ba96b245eae82fb4_variable  0B/287B (0.0%)
2023-10-13T11:56:35.257+0200    [........................] opal_data.65290895ba96b245eae82fb4_variable  0B/287B (0.0%)
```

The collection exists, for the import I have used a validator to verify the JSON as well as try multiple JSON files. The collection name is also copied directly from inside MongoDB and I am able to pull data from the collection using Python.

My mongo shell version is 3.6.8 and the container runs mongo server 6.0.10.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: The collection name you specify `65290895ba96b245eae82fb4_variable` is odd.  Try the command with a normalized collection name, like 'mycollection'.

Comment: @barrypicker I created a new collection named "test" and tried to import the json files, but again it gets stuck on 0% uploading.